# Program Crashes on Debugging

Tags: c#, soap, visual-studio-2012

I am new to C# this is kind of my first program. I am trying to integrate a SOAPI from OVH.IE (more info here: [www.ovh.ie/products/soapi.xml](http://www.ovh.ie/products/soapi.xml)), but whenever I launch the program and click the login button the program crashes (memory usage of VS2012 increases and then crashes).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace Server_Manager
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear(); 
    }

    void login(string uid, string pwd, string dc)
    {
        if (dc == "OVH")
        {
            managerService soapi = new managerService();
            string session = soapi.login(uid, pwd, "ie", false);
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(session))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not Logged");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Logged In");
            }
        }

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Fill all the Details");
        }
        else
        {
            string uid, pwd, dc;
            uid = textBox1.Text;
            pwd = textBox2.Text;
            dc = comboBox1.Text;
            login(uid,pwd,dc);
        }
        MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.Text);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Do you get any exception message when it crashes?

Comment: does the api support the .net framework version?

Comment: I think you are calling login inside login function.

Comment: @sajanyamaha, he is calling login on another object.

Comment: @urlreader Yes the api supports the .net framework.

Comment: I am getting this error a fatal error has occurred and debugging needs to be terminated HRESULT = 0x8007000e Error Code 0x0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These instructions are for diagnosing this in WinDBG, a command line based debugger from microsoft, but I have been told they *can* work in Visual Studio.

1. Start up the application
2. Start up WinDBG and attach to the application
3. Type in ".loadby sos clr" (assuming >=4.0 framework)
4. Type "dumpheap -stat"
5. Look over the results, for suspicious objects type "dumpheap -mt {0}" where {0} is replaced by the objects MT address
6. If you don't know why objects are alive, type "gcroot {0}" passing an object address from above

Comment: i cant find WinDBG option anywhere i am using VS2012.

Comment: It is part of the windows debugging toolkit:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx